# Не удается отредактировать internal storage файл в сторонних приложениях

Tags: android

Стоит задача - отправить на редактирование файл, находящийся во внутренней памяти, в `files` директории.

*files-path* есть.

`Uri` формируется правильно.

`Intent` на `ACTION_EDIT` с флагами `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`, `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION`.

Сторонние приложения файл открывают (например формата `docx`), но редактировать не могут. Пробовал `Context.grantUriPermissions` - не помогает. *Android developers* говорит, что можно читать и редактировать файлы `internal storage`, но на деле не выходит.

Возможно ли это вообще, или нужно юзать `getExternalFilesDir`?

Comment: что говорят методы `canRead()/canWrite()`? Да, и покажите `file_paths.xml` с указанием какой раздел используется `external-path` или `files_path`